# js script stops working when exported from ejs to an external file

Tags: javascript, local-storage, ejs

I've written a table management function that checks for default categories that the user has saved for himself; it runs on conditions managed with the help of localStorage then shows a loading screen for a few seconds (managed by two simple functions that modifies the styling that I won't paste here to not clutter the post with even more code) and auto-fills the query with the categories.

The problem is, however, everything works just fine right until I export the code to an external js file.

Here's what the function looks like:

```
const setDefault = async function() { 

    document.querySelector('#loading-div').style.display = 'none'

    let userTable = '<%- JSON.stringify(userTable) %>'
    let queryString = '<%- JSON.stringify(queryString) %>'


    if 
    (((!queryString.includes('added') && !queryString.includes('catalogue') && !queryString.includes('acquired') && !queryString.includes('arch-col') && !queryString.includes('forSale')) && (queryString.includes('archival-hide') || queryString.includes('archival-show') || queryString.includes('archival-showOnly')))) {
    localStorage.setItem('noBoxesChecked', true)} else { localStorage.removeItem('noBoxesChecked')};

    if (localStorage.getItem("defaultCollectionSettings") === null && localStorage.getItem("noBoxesChecked") === null) {

    

        showLoading();

        await sleep(800);

        const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".category-check");

        for (let el of document.querySelectorAll('.category-check')) {
            if (!queryString.includes("1")){
            if (userTable.includes(el.name)){ el.checked = 1 } else { 
                el.checked = 0 
        }          

    }}

        for (let o of document.querySelector("#archival-select")) {
        if (!queryString.includes("1")) {
            if (userTable.includes(o.value)){ o.selected = 1 } else {
                o.selected = 0
            }
        }
        }


    document.querySelector('#collection_form').submit();
    localStorage.setItem("defaultCollectionSettings", true) 

    } else {
    localStorage.removeItem('defaultCollectionSettings');

    window.onload = (function(){
    setDefault()
})
}};
```

Afterwards I call it with:

```
window.onload = (function(){
    setDefault()
})
```

which I have tried both in the external file and inside the ejs which didn't make a difference.

First thing I did, I've double checked my links. No problem there. Linked in the same way all the other working js scripts are linked.

I've also looked for answers on stack but similar problems were solved all the same: by correcting relative urls inside the js file and by removing the left-over script tags. My code doesn't have these problems.

I'd be thankful if someone could show me what am I missing here, as I've already sat an hour in front of this with no success.